# Express app won't let me check what's inside req

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js

I know my problem may seem not very specific, but I'm having problem describing what's happening because I don't understand it :(
So I've written small express app with ssr (for react) and jwt authentication. The SSR part works nice but the rest is crap.....

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import logger from 'morgan';
import authRouter from './auth/authRouter';

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: '*/*' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//a lot of irrelevant ssr code

authRouter(app);

app.listen(3000, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log('main server on port 3000');
});
```

This is my main server file. My first problem is I don't see ANY console.logs from my files. There's nothing in my terminal. That's the reason I can't see how does my requests look like in my app. I'm testing it using postman like that:
[image: postman]

And that's the authRouter I'm using above in main server file:

```
import express from 'express';
import { signup, signin } from '../controllers/authentication';
import { jwtLogin, localLogin } from '../services/passport';
import passport from 'passport';

passport.use(jwtLogin);
passport.use(localLogin);
//if user is auth'd do not create session for him
const requireAuth = passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false });
const requireSignin = passport.authenticate('local', { session: false });

const authRouter = function(app) {
  app.get('/auth', requireAuth, function(req, res) {
    res.send({ hi: 'there' });
  });
  app.post('/auth/signin', requireSignin, signin); // irrelevant right now
  app.post('/auth/signup', signup);
};
export default authRouter;
```

And that's signup function I'm using in router:

```
const signup = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('reqqqqqqq', req);
  const { email, password, passwordCheck } = req.body; //code crashes here

  //some code I deleted for everyones convenience
};
```

Every request I make my app crashes because req.body is undefined. I can't log req because I can't see any logs. I also tried sending back stringified version of my request body but every time i get "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON".
I'll be happy to add any information you may need

**EDIT:**
I'm gonna check that later at home but now I'm thinking there is something wrong with ssr part of my app because I don't even see that 'main server on port 3000' log..... At the same time server responds with right html, js files and routing works well so.....anyway I'm gonna look it up later

Comment: Odd, can you debug the application calling the console statements? My only assumption would be your application is failing before it hits any logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.....unexpectedly the problem was lying in my package.json file.
My start script looked like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon build/server.bundle.js | nodemon build/api.bundle.js",
    ...
  }
```

And because of that I had these weird errors. Only api.bundle.js file was running correctly......
Anyway thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_showhidden_depth_colors) from node:

```
const util = require('util');

// usage in your code
const signup = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(util.inspect(req, { showHidden: true, depth: null }));
  const { email, password, passwordCheck } = req.body;
  ...
};
```